# Separate js-code for desktop and mobile visitors in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails app that have 50 or so js-functions organized in separate files, in the app/assets/javascripts folder.

I'm now starting to remake certain pages for mobile visitors, detecting them in the controller with the method:

```
def mobile_agent?
  request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Android)/]
end
```

and serving them separate views that content-wise are completely different from the "desktop" views.

I don't want the javascript files (and it's code) used for the desktop visitors to load for the mobile visitors, and vice versa.

One way could be to skip loading the js-assets alltogether with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" unless mobile_agent? %>
```

but where do I then put my mobile js-files?

Or any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many manifest files as you want.  Just put them in **/app/assets/javascripts** and they will be compiled automatically.  You can have:

**mobile.js:**

```
//= require sharedjs
//= require mobilejs
```

**desktop.js:**

```
//= require sharedjs
//= require desktopjs
```

And then in your **layout** file, something like:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" if mobile_agent? %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "desktop" unless mobile_agent? %>
```

Comment: And to further organize stuff you can create a subfolder with all device specific files and require them like so  
 `//= require_tree ./desktop`